# How can i store separate data from an FormArray into an normal object array in Angular

Tags: angular

This is my object containing array stations in which I wanna store data from routeForm, FormArray "stationsName" (after i added data to stationsName array through form)

```
Routes = {
    name : '',
    departureDate: '',
    arrivalDate: '',
    stations: [{
      name: '',
      arrival: ''
    }]
  }

  routeForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      stationsName: new FormArray([])
  });


 get f() {
 return this.routeForm.controls;
 }
 get stationsName() {
 return this.f.stationsName as FormArray;
 }

 addNewStationName() {
 this.stationsName.push(
 this.formBuilder.group({
 name: ['', []],
 arrival: ['', []]
 })
 );
 }
```

How can i do something like this:

```
this.Routes.stations[0].name = this.routeForm.stationsName[0].name.value

this.Routes.stations[0].arrival = this.routeForm.stationsname[0].arrival.value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.routeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   stationsName: new FormArray([])
 });
 this.routeForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data=>{
   this.Routes.stations = data.stationsName;
 });
}
```